# validating phone number on Reactjs form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm working on a front end application and have to add validation to the form. I'm new to ReactJS to learning on my way to development.

There is an input field for phoneNumber that needs to be numbers only. so there should be a red warning text below the input field which says "Only numbers!" if anyone enters alphabet.
I written a handleChange for onChange.but it doesn't seem to work. The console on web browser throws this error: originalOnChangeEvent is not a function.

updateCustomerInfoValues is using the useReducer hook. Struggling here to call both hook and  function for onChange.

CustomerFields.jsx

```
 import React, { } from 'react';
 const CustomerFields = (props) => {
   const {
    customerInfo,
    updateCustomerInfoValues
   }= props;
   const errors={
     firstName: '',
     phoneNumber: '',
     userEmail: '',
   }
   function handleChange(event){
    updateCustomerInfoValues
    event.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    let errors = state.errors;

    if (!customerInfo.phoneNumber.match(/^[0-9\b]+$/)) {
        errors.customerInfo  = 'Only numbers';
      }
    setState({errors, errors})
    }
  return (
        <div className="caption font-large">Customer Data</div>
        <div className="customer-input-field">
            <InputField
                inputType="text"
                fieldName="firstName"
                label="FirstName"
                htmlAttributes={{
                    onChange: updateCustomerInfoValues,
                    value: customerInfo.firstName
                }}
            />
            <InputField
                inputType="text"
                fieldName="phoneNumber"
                label="Phone Number"
                htmlAttributes={{
                    onChange: {handleChange},
                    value: customerInfo.phoneNumber
                }}
            />
          </div>
         );
       };
```

MainForm.jsx

```
 import React, { useMemo, useState, useEffect, useCallback, useReducer } from 'react';
 import CustomerFields from './CustomerFields';

 const MainForm = (props) => {
    const [customerInfo, updateCustomerInfo] = useReducer(formUpdateFieldValues, result.customerInfo);
 return (
 <Form>
 <div id="post-customer">
     <div id="post-customer-content">
     <CustomerFields
         customerInfo={customerInfo}
         updateCustomerInfoValues={updateCustomerInfo}
     />
  </div>
 </Form>
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I recommend to use Formik and yup libraries.
Formik will help you to organise your form and it also supports yup. 
Yup will help you with validation. It has bunch of different validation templates and support regular expressions. 
If one of your input fields is incorrect, it will in real time send an error message (not in console, but as property of your function, which will return your form), which you can handle in your input component.
Formik - https://formik.org/docs/overview 
Yup - https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup 
Error handling - https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation 
**And also you can find or write your own phone number reg exp.**